# <input type="number"> in Firefox. Why doesn't Mozilla support number inputs in its browser?

Tags: html, firefox, numbers, html-input

It's strange. Input number is a standard for W3C, but it doesn't work on Firefox yet.

Is there some trick for using input number on Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

It's a proposed standard, not a standard.  There's a difference.

There's no trick to it; it's just not supported yet on desktop Firefox (FirefoxOS and Firefox on Android may have an implementation; it's not clear to me whether they do).

Answer (score 1):

You can see current traction here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344616