# decimal input is missing with Cordova shell in Samsung 4.3

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile, htcsense, samsung-mobile-sdk

For my hybrid app using in both Samsung v4.3 above and HTC, keyboard is not showing the decimal point while input type=Number. But it is working fine in browser using the same samsung and htc phone.

Kindly help me to get a solution for this issue.

Comment: Same here... Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205511/what-models-of-samsung-smartphones-have-missing-period-for-html5-input-type-num/23994285#23994285?